# Is it possible to make an element ignore position:relative?

Tags: jquery, css, position

Just want to know if it is possible to make an element ignore any wrappers with position:relative.

I'm creating elements with jQuery which is being placed with position absolute, and needs to work no matter how the user is placing their elements.

I can't place them in the BODY-tag, because I need to place them inside a wrapper together with an inputfield.

Any ideas?

UPDATE:
Found a workaround. I was using jQuery .offset() which is getting position of the document.
Edited it to .position() which is getting position of the element inside the parent. Now it works

Comment: Nope, I don't think so. A popular workaround is using jQuery to cut & paste the element to a location outside the wrapper

Comment: Why dont you add the wrapper to the body, which contains your element and the inputfield? Unless im missing something?

Comment: @Alex Thomas: The wrapper has `position: relative`, and may be moved around, carrying the element along with it.

Comment: I don't get it, but could you just use javascript to set it to position : static ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something, but you can monitor for a resize event and then re-position your element.
http://api.jquery.com/resize/

Comment: It dosnt have anything to do with the resize. The problem is that i have a form, and inside that there are inputfields. When the user clicks the input field, im placing an error box on the input field. The position is calculated with the inputbox position, and then placed in the corner. But if the user have a form with possition relative, the errorboxes is being placed wrong.

Comment: @BoltClock: I agree with QuakeDK, i think we're going to need to see some example site and or code.

Answer (score 0):

A though would be to set the left and top attributes as if there were no position: relative-parents and add lets say class "body_pos":

```
$(function() {
  $('.body_pos').each(function() {
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    $(this).css({
      left : '-='+offset.left,
      top : '-='+offset.top
    });
  });
});
```

Example: You've set left: 50px, the element is positioned at left: 100px in the document, then it will be positioned left: -50px.

It should grant desired effect as long as it's not positioned inside a margin: 0 auto box, and the window is resized I suppose.

Comment: Im not sure if this is what your ment, but i tried to remove the position:absolute, and only use left, top, but then it dosnt affect the element ?

Comment: This is a clever workaround, but will work only if the parent container's `overflow` is not set to `hidden`.

Comment: Was going to suggest `offset()`. is `position()` effected by and elements overflow? @Pekka

Comment: @Alex yup. If `overflow` is `hidden`, the element will be cut off.